# Infinite scrolling: Loading more data with Ajax call?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I’m trying to implement an infinite scroll table that displays user’s name, address and email. First, I imported json-server package and created an API endpoint with fakerjs in a separate file called users.js to serve on localhost:

```
var faker = require('faker')

function generateUsers () {
  var users = [];
  var loading = true;
  for(var i=0;i<50;i++) {
    var name = faker.name.findName()
    var email = faker.internet.email()
    var city = faker.address.city()
    var country = faker.address.country()
    users.push({
      "name": name,
      "email": email,
      "city": city,
      "country": country
    })
  }
  return { "users": users }
}
module.exports = generateUsers
```

My question is “How can I load another batch of 50 users every time I scroll to the end of the page?” On initial loading, it only loads in 50 users as specified in the user.js file. I was thinking I could push more data into the user array in the ajax success function, but I'm not sure how to implement it.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var currentPageNumber = 1;
    loadMore(currentPageNumber);
$(window).scroll(function() {

    if($(window).scrollTop() ==  $(document).height()- $(window).height())
    {

        loadMore(currentPageNumber);
        currentPageNumber +=1;
    }
  });
    function loadMore(currentPage){
        $.ajax({
            method: "GET",
            url: "http://localhost:3000/users?_page="+ currentPage,
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(data) {
                var  last = data[data.length-1];
                    for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++) {

                       $('tbody').append("<tr><td>"+ data[i].name+"</td><td>"+ 
                       data[i].email+"</td><td>" 
                       + data[i].city + "," + data[i].country+ "</td></tr>")




            },
            error: function(data) {
                    console.log("Something went wrong!");
            }

    })
}
```

Comment: does `loadMore` get called more than once? perhaps your logic for triggering `loadMore` is flawed - also, I think you need to `currentPageNumber +=1;` **before** calling `loadMore`

Comment: loadMore() gets triggered whenever the user hits the end of the page. But the json-server only create a fixed number of data points (in this case 50). So loadMore() stops working after 50 data points finished being loaded...

Comment: ahhh, I get it now. Sorry, I thought the server side code you showed `generateUsers` simply gets called every time you hit `http://localhost:3000/users?_page=` - my bad - it's not clear how `generateUsers` is being used (at all) in the snippet you shared

Comment: You're right. I was thinking if I could import generateUsers into the main file (where I wrote the ajax call logic)  and after the success function, use generateUsers to get another set of 50 more users?

Comment: Does the request actually happen when the user hits the end of the page? do the results match with what you expect to get? Maybe there's just a problem with the append. Btw. what is the "last" param used for? i can't see any use of it

Comment: Yes the request did happen. It loads 10 items each time then another 10 items until 50 , it stops loading when I scrolls to the top. Please ignore the last param. I forgot to delete it. It's just something I was testing.

Answer (score 1):

There are some typos in your javascript, try with the code below (I wrote you some comments with my suggestions)

```
var currentPageNumber = 1; // initialization before all functions

$(document).ready(function(){
    loadMore(currentPageNumber);
});

$(window).scroll(function() {
    if( $(window).scrollTop() == $(document).height() - $(window).height() ){
        currentPageNumber++; //increment by one before calling again loadMore()
        loadMore(currentPageNumber);
    }
});

function loadMore(currentPage){

    $.ajax({
        method: "GET",
        url: "http://localhost:3000/users?_page="+ currentPage,
        dataType: 'json',
        cache: false, //avoid browser cache ajax requests
        success: function(data) {

            $.each(data, function(key, val) { // use jQuery.each, easier and clean

                $('tbody').append("<tr><td>"+ val.name+"</td><td>"+ 
                val.email+"</td><td>" 
                + val.city + "," + val.country+ "</td></tr>");

            });

        },
        error: function(data) {
            console.log("Something went wrong!")
        }
    });

}
```